# SPRING SECURITY - ALWAYS MOVING TO authentication-failure-url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring security and i am learning it by writing some sample code. But the problem is securityContext is always redirecting me to  authentication-failure-url. cant understand what's wrong with the code.

here are the snippets

SecurityContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/userhome**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/"
        login-processing-url="/login"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" 
        default-target-url="/userhome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login.do?error" 
        always-use-default-target="true"
         />

    <logout logout-success-url="/login.do?logout" />





    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
        <user name="u" password="u" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
      </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Controller Class : UsersLoginController

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class UsersLoginController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/login.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,@RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout , HttpServletRequest request) {

    System.out.println(request.getParameter("username"));
    System.out.println(error);

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    if (error != null) {
        model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }
    model.setViewName("/index");



    return model;

}


@RequestMapping(value = "/userhome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView userhome() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

    model.setViewName("/WEB-INF/jsp/LoginCheck/UserHome");



    return model;

}




}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

<form:form action="./login" method="GET" >

<table align="Center">

<tr><td id="tdlogin">Email Address</td><td><input type=text name="username" id="username"/> </td></tr>
<tr><td id="tdlogin">Password</td><td><input type=text name="password" id="password"/> </td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="staySignIn" value="staySignIn"> Stay Sign In </td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="Submit" id="Submit" Value="SUMBIT"> </td></tr>

</table>

</form:form>

    <core:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="error">${error}</div>
    </core:if>
    <core:if test="${not empty msg}">
        <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
    </core:if>

</body>
</html>
```

any suggestions regarding how to make things work would be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your login-processing-url is `/login` and you have GET instead of POST on your login page form goes to `/login.do`. Correct this

```
<form-login login-page="/"
        login-processing-url="/login"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" 
        default-target-url="/userhome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login.do?error" 
        always-use-default-target="true"
         />
```

Login Form must also change

```
<form:form action="/login" method="POST" >

<table align="Center">

<tr><td id="tdlogin">Email Address</td><td><input type=text name="username" id="username"/> </td></tr>
<tr><td id="tdlogin">Password</td><td><input type=text name="password" id="password"/> </td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="staySignIn" value="staySignIn"> Stay Sign In </td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="Submit" id="Submit" Value="SUMBIT"> </td></tr>

</table>

</form:form>

    <core:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="error">${error}</div>
    </core:if>
    <core:if test="${not empty msg}">
        <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
    </core:if>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that worked . thanks . but why "post" method ? but why not "get" method ??

Comment: If you use form-login xml tag then you must use POST. If you want POST or GET then you have to custom register UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter with postOnly flag set to false. Please read following post to know how to custom register  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2014/02/spring-security-custom-filterchainproxy.html

Answer (score 1):

Are the username and password parameter names correct in mvc config correct?

```
    username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
```

Here is a very good tutorial

http://www.journaldev.com/2736/spring-mvc-security-example-using-in-memory-userdetailsservice-and-jdbc-authentication